# How can I exclude a specific page in a custom footer in Divi?

Tags: divi

Does anybody here use the Divi theme? I tried adding a custom footer and have to exclude it on a specific page but doesn't seem to work. The custom footer section comes up on the page I excluded although I have excluded it in the builder. I'm sure I selected the correct page. I don't know if this is a bug or I just missed something.

Thank you in advance for your response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used divi several months ago. If you are using custom global footer, you can not exclude this. Just hide it in specific pages

```
.page-id-1098 #main-footer {
    display: none;
}
```